# How to cast to a polymorphic type with a member not in interface

Tags: java

I have an interface like

```
public interface IFoo {
    String getX();
    ...
}
```

and have several classes like

```
public class Bar implements IFoo {
    public String getX() {
        ...
    }

    public String getY() {
        ...
    }
}
```

The important thing here is that all of the classes that implement `IFoo`, like `Bar`, have the `String getY()` method, but this method is not part of the `IFoo` interface.

Now, I have some XML that I need to deserialize to a Java object. The XML can be an object of any of the `IFoo` implementing classes, but after deserializing, I will need to use the `String getY()` method.

Are there any concise or elegant ways to achieve this?

I have created another interface like

```
public interface IFooExtension extends IFoo {
    String getY();
}
```

and have tried creating an instance of it like

```
String xml = ...;
IFooExtension fooExtension = (IFooExtension) XMLBeanSerializer.deserialize(xml);
```

but get an error when casting the XML to the object that says something object `Instance of Bar cannot be cast to an object of type IFooExtension`

ANSWERS:

- The answers from `GhostCat` and `Edwin Dalorzo` are both great.

  - `GhostCat` explains that this is not possible in Java out of the box because Java does not support *duck typing*
  - `Edwin Dalorzo` provides a workaround for this issue by applying the *Adapter* design pattern

Comment: `Bar` will need to implement `IFooExtension`. Java doesn't have ducktyping.

Comment: An adapter pattern could help you achieve what you want. Just wrap your object (adaptee) into another that implement both `Foo` and `FooExt` where ideally `FooExt extends Foo`, then use `FooExt` as the type you use in your code in question. Your problem is that the deserialized object won’t ever implement `FooExt`, so you can put every possible type in an adapter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From my understanding of your question, you know that `XMLBeanSerializer.deserialize(xml)` is going to give you a specific kind of object, an object of type `A`, `B` or `C`. Those types you know in advance.

Now, you also know that `A`, `B`, and `C` have a method with signature `int getX()`, but none of these types have a common interface with that method.

You also know that `A`, `B`, and `C` do have a common interface type `Foo` that implements `int getY()`. So, all the objects you deserialize can be assigned to a reference of type `Foo` and gain access to `int getY()`, but there is not a type that you can use for all those objects to gain access to both methods `int getX()` and `int getY()`.

That's my understanding of your problem and based on that I believe we can implement a solution with an [adapter pattern](https://refactoring.guru/design-patterns/adapter).

So, to start you have a common interface:

```java
interface Foo {
   int getY();
}
```

And a few deserializable objects from classes that implement it, plus an additional method:

```java
class A implements Foo {
    @Override
    public int getY() { return 1; }
    public int getX() { return 0; }
}

class B implements Foo {
    @Override
    public int getY() { return 2; }
    public int getX() { return 0; }
}

class C implements Foo {
    @Override
    public int getY() { return 3; }
    public int getX() { return 0; }
}
```

So, how can I deserialize an object of any of these classes and gain access to both methods through a common interface?

#### Adapter Solution

Well, obviously we can't do it the way it is. As other answers have pointed out, Java does not have duck typing.

However, we can simply build a new type hierarchy in which the classes implement both methods.

We start with an interface `FooExt` that exposes both methods.

```java
interface FooExt extends Foo {
   int getX();
}
```

Then we define an adapter class hierarchy based on this new interface:

```java
class AAdapter implements FooExt {
    private final A adaptee;

    AAdapter(A adaptee) {
       this.adaptee = adaptee;
    }

    @Override
    public int getY() { return adaptee.getY(); }

    @Override
    public int getX() { return adaptee.getX(); }
}

class BAdapter implements FooExt {
  //TODO: implement adapter
}

class CAdapter implements FooExt {
    //TODO: implement adapter
}
```

And now we can do something like this:

```java
public FooExt deserialize(String xlm) {
   Object obj = XMLBeanSerializer.deserialize(xml);
   if (obj instanceof A a) {
       return new AAdapter(a);
   } 
   if (obj instanceof B b) {
      return new BAdapter(b);
   } 
   if (obj instanceof C c) {
      return new BAdapter(c);
   } 
   throw new AssertionError("Unknown object type: " + obj);
}
```

As you can see the adapter pattern uses [delegation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delegation_pattern) (which is a form of [object composition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_composition)) instead of inheritance to adapt the object to a new interface that support both methods.

This follows that principle of: "Favor composition over inheritance".

Finally, in the call site we can do somewhat as follows:

```java
FooExt fe = deserialize(xml);
int x = fe.getX(); 
int y = fe.getY();
```

#### Proxy Solution

The following is a proxy-based version of the code that would save you the time of having to implement a full class hierarchy.

A [proxy pattern](https://refactoring.guru/design-patterns/proxy) can help you wrap the adapted in a reflection handler that can help you find the method you want to invoke.

So, consider the following code to create a proxy around the adapted. The proxy is of type `FooExt`.

```java
static FooExt createProxyAdapter(Foo adaptee) {
    ClassLoader cl = Foo.class.getClassLoader();
    Object adapter = Proxy.newProxyInstance(cl, new Class<?>[]{FooExt.class},
            (Object proxy, Method method, Object[] args) -> {
                if(method.getName().endsWith("getX")) {
                    //then find the method in the adaptee
                    var m = adaptee.getClass().getMethod("getX");
                    return m.invoke(adaptee);
                }
                //otherwise call the method from FooExt.
                return method.invoke(adaptee, args);
            });
    return (FooExt) adapter;
}
```

And now you can do somewhat as follows:

```java
Foo a = new A();
FooExt fa = createProxyAdapter(a);

int y = fa.getY();
int x = fa.getX();
```

Works like a charm!

If there are too many classes to adapt, then this solution is, perhaps, preferable. If there are only a few classes, then I would prefer the first one, since I would consider the code easier to maintain, debug, follow, etc.

Whether you consider these two ideas an elegant solution or not is an entirely different discussion :-)

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I thought there must be some design pattern to achieve this.

Comment: I considered some of the comments and I also added an additional solution based on a proxy pattern, in case you want to check that out out as well. A bit simpler, but requires some Java reflection, which is less than ideal from my point of view. If there are not many classes, I would prefer the statically-typed-based adapter, i.e. solution #1.

Answer (score 3):

This is simply **not** possible in Java.

In order for any class X to be casted to some interface Y, there absolutely must be `X implements Y` in the source code side of things (or: a parent class of X doing that).

Java does **not** support the idea of "call me Y because I have all methods of Y" (in the sense of some object "being an instance of Y, because it has all Y methods).

Comment: Well, there’s reflection. Which, in the context of (de)serialisation, *might* be appropriate.

Comment: Reflection allows you to **invoke** methods when you know they exist. And well, you can create dynamic proxies and such things, but that doesn't change what I said about *casting*.

Comment: My comment was in response to the last sentence of your answer, not the statement about casting. Anyway, I don’t mean to to detract from your answer in general. — Stepping outside the type system (which is what reflection would do) is *not* recommended for general usage, for good reason.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I knew there was some concept I was forgetting -- ducktyping. This makes sense. Accepting the other answer just because it does provide a solution for my issue.